# Grep all content of File 1 from File 2

Tags: shell, unix

This is regarding grepping all the Thread IDs which are mentioned in one file from the thread dump file in unix.

I also require at least 5 lines below each thread id from thread dump while grepping.

Like below:-
MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out:

```
1001
1003
```

MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt:

```
............TDID=1001..................
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7

............TDID=1002...................
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
...........TDID=1003......................
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
```

Output should contain :-

```
............TDID=1001..................
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

...........TDID=1003......................
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

If possible I would like to have the above output in the mail body.

I have tried the below code but it sends me the thread IDs in the body with thread dump file as an attachment
How ever I would like to have the description of each thread id in the body of the mail only

```
JAVA_HOME=/u01/oracle/products/jdk

MAX_CPU_PID=`ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -2 | sed -n '1!p' | awk '{print $1}'`

ps -eLo pid,ppid,tid,pcpu,comm | grep $MAX_CPU_PID  > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess.out
cat MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess.out | awk '{ print "pccpu: "$4" pid: "$1" ppid: "$2" ttid: "$3" comm: "$5}' |sort -n > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp1.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess.out

sort -k 2n MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp1.out  > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp2.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp1.out

awk '{a[i++]=$0}END{for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)print a[j];}' MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp2.out > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp3.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp2.out

awk '($2 > 15 ) ' MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp3.out > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_Highest_Consuming.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp3.out

awk '{ print $8 }' MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_Highest_Consuming.out > MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp4.out
( echo "obase=16" ; cat MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp4.out ) | bc > MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids_temp.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_SubProcess_Sorted_temp4.out

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jstack -l $MAX_CPU_PID > MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt
#grep -i -A 10 'error' data

awk 'BEGIN{print "The below thread IDs from the attached thread dump of OUD1 server are causing the highest CPU utilization. Please Analyze it further\n"}1' MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids_temp.out > MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out
rm MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids_temp.out

tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out | mailx -s "OUD1 MAX CPU Utilization Analysis" -a MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt <My Mail ID>
```

Comment: It is not clear how the two files `File1` and `File2` and the output are related to the code. You should use the same file names as in the code or add comments to the code to make clear where the data appear. Basically you have two separate questions: How to filter the data based on `File1` and `File2` and how to send a mail with the file contents in the body. For sending the mail, please describe how the complete mail body should look like. Please [edit] your question, don't answer in comments.

Comment: I have edited the question with the file names from the code. Please let me know if anyone can help

Comment: 1) Basically i have taken the output of the highest CPU consuming PIDs.

2) Based on the highest consuming PID, i found the sub process IDs. and sort them with max usage. I am taking only the sub process ids which are consuming greater than 15% for that process.

3) I am converting those sub process ids TID from deimal to hexadecimal to grep those information from thread dump.

4) Then i need to grep each thread id from the list which is stored in MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out from thread dump file MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt.

Comment: `grep -F -f MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out -A 5 MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt`?

Comment: 5) I require at least 10 lines of output for each thread ID. like wise for all the thread ids from thread dump into the mail body.

Comment: @SmitDani I suggest to add the numbered explanation from your comments here **to the question** as comments in the script. (I think the script can be optimized, and the comments may help.)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for the first part: How to extract the lines.**

The solution with `grep -F -f MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out -A 5 MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt` as proposed in a comment is much simpler, but it may fail if the lines `Line 1` etc can contain the values from `MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out`. It may also print a non-matching `TDID=` line if there are not enough lines after the previous matching line.
For the `grep` solution it may be better to create a file with patterns like `...TDID=1001...`.

The following script will print the matching lines `...TDID=XYZ...` and at most the following 5 lines. It will stop after fewer lines if a new `...TDID=XYZ...` is found.

For simplicity an empty line is printed before every `...TDID=XYZ...` line, i.e. also before the first one.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {ids[$1]=1;next} # from the first file save all IDs as array keys
/\.\.\.TDID=/ { 
   sel = 0;        # stop any previous output
   id=gensub(/\.*TDID=([^.]*)\.*/,"\\1",1); # extract ID
   if(id in ids) { # select if ID is present in array
      print ""     # empty line as separator
      sel = 1;
   }
   count = 0;      # counter to limit number of lines
}
sel {              # selected for output?
   print; 
   count++;
   if(count > 5) { # stop after ...TDID= + 5 more lines (change the number if necessary)
      sel = 0     
   }
}' MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt > MAX_CPU_PID_TD.extract
```

Apart from the first empty line, this script produces the expected output from the example input as shown in the question. If it does not work with the real input or if there are additional requirements, update the question to show the problematic input and the expected output or the additional requirements.

**Answer for the second part: Mail formatting**

To get the resulting data into the mail body you simply have to pipe it into `mailx` instead of specifying the file as an attachment.

```
( tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids.out ; cat MAX_CPU_PID_TD.extract ) | mailx -s "OUD1 MAX CPU Utilization Analysis" <My Mail ID>
```

Comment: Hi Bodo,

Thank you for the reply.

But i am only getting the 5 lines of the last value in file 1 from file 2.

Let me put everything in here.
Basically:-
I have below file to read:-
MAX_CPU_PID_TD_Ids_temp.out
===========================
98D7
98D6
98D5
977C
9776
9775

Now from the below file[MAX_CPU_PID_TD.txt] where the above Thread Id is mentioned as below [nid=0x977c]: I would require at least 10 lines below the line detected in another out file. so for each id mentioned in above file.

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff80411b800 nid=0x977c in ...
...

Comment: @SmitDani My script works with the example from your question. I don't understand what problem you have now. Please show the problematic input and the expected output **in your question**. If the only problem is the number of lines (10 instead of 5), simply change `if(count > 5)` to `if(count > 10)`.